# OS X slow getting directory listing on CentOs

Tags: centos, afp

If you log in to our CentOs server on Windows 7 the directory listing is very fast.  If you log in using OS X 10.9.4, it can take a couple of minutes before it will display the folder contents.  It does not matter if you use SMB or AFP mounts, the result is the same.  The delay is there for every subsequent folder you click into.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "log in", do you really mean "mount the Centos filesystem and try to browse it from the Mac"?

Comment: Yes.  Stack says I need some more letters here.